# replace() in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, replace

how are you all!.
I have a type of data "RefCFuenteFinanciamiento" type string and I want to compare it in a  with a PkId type number.
The problem is that the data RefCFuenteFinanciamiento has a value "19745" with spaces and the Pk is 19745 I would like to eliminate those spaces.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIp6c.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to remove spaces in a string? var str = '1 97 45' => '19745'?

Comment: That's right, it's a value that I bring a list and the value is type string = "19745     " I want to erase the spaces at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim the string and remove trailing spaces by calling `.trim()` on your string.

```js
str = "19745 ";
console.log(str.trim());
```

Comment: Yes this will run fine in typescript or bound in angular.